# Regression of a linear combination of exponential decay functions

Tags: multiple-regression, nonlinear-regression, exponential-distribution

I have $n$ data points that I would like to model via somewhat of a classical linear regression model like this, where $i$ is one of the $n$ data points:

$w_1x_1^{i}+w_2x_2^{i}+...+w_mx_m^{i} = y^{i}$

However what I'm really thinking about is having each $w_j$ coefficient to represent some sort of exponential decay. In other words:

$w_j = e^{-k/t_{j}^{i}}$

where each weight $w_j$ is not actually a constant but is a variable weighted by observation time $t_{j,i}$ for a specific trial. The final model should look something like this:

$e^{-k/t_{1}^i}x_1^{i}+e^{-k/t_{2}^i}x_2^{i}+...+e^{-k/t_{m}^i}x_m^{i} = y^{i}$

I am not quite sure where to start to perform this regression. It does seems though that the variable I should be fitting is $k$ which controls the rate of decay of my exponential functions. But am I trying to solve an under-constrained problem?
In addition to not knowing how to do the regression, I have the problem of having a variable number of data points per trial. In other words one data points might have $m=3$, and in another case I might have $m=7$. I'd say I have about $n=10000$ data points. I think a work around this might be to just create dummy variables and give them a small observation time $t_j^i$ such that the weight $w_j$ goes to zero. 
What type of regression are we talking about here? 
Any suggestions on what I should read to know more about this?

Some other ideas: I could just treat all the weights $w$ as constants and then perform a non-linear regression on those coefficients. Would that work and/or is that theoretically acceptable?

Comment: Assuming the $t_j^i$ are known, as well as the $x_j^i$ and $y_i$, then this is a nonlinear univariate model.  You ought to think about how you wish to model the differences between the $y_i$ and their fitted values: that will determine what quantity to optimize as you vary $k$ and reduce this to an easily solved problem.

Comment: @whuber the values you mentioned above are known, so I will look into nonlinear univariate modelling, thanks!

Comment: For the problem of variable number of datapoints per trial look into multiple instance learning. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_instance_learning